# Is it possible to open each hyperlinks inside the pdf in various tabs of the browser?

Tags: pdf, adobe, acrobat, pdf-viewer

I have a pdf which has various hyperlinks inside. Each hyperlinks pointing to various url locations. When I click on each link it opens in the same tab in the browser. So I need to click back button again and again to view the source pdf. Is it possible to open each link in a new tab in browser. I am using firefox/Safari browsers.

Comment: Sounds like a browser configuration issue. What is the value of "Open windows in a new tab"?

Comment: Its checked. I am using mac